# Extract a single line from a webpage VB2008

Tags: vb.net

I'm looking to extract only the line that starts "A SUNOT..." from this website. https://pilotweb.nas.faa.gov/common/nat.html

I then want to paste that line into a text box in VB2008.

I tried using:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim TrackA As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create("https://pilotweb.nas.faa.gov/common/nat.html")
        Dim gather As System.Net.HttpWebResponse = TrackA.GetResponse
        Dim write As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(gather.GetResponseStream)
        RawData.Text = write.ReadLine(?)
    End Sub
End Class
```

I got it to write the entire page but I wanted just that line.
The '?' is to show if that ReadLine command is the right thing to be using there.

Thanks, James

Comment: You may want to look into using the WebBrowser control - it is easier for scraping applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim TrackA As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create("https://pilotweb.nas.faa.gov/common/nat.html")
    Dim gather As System.Net.HttpWebResponse = TrackA.GetResponse
    Dim write As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(gather.GetResponseStream)

    Dim ContentStr As String = write.ReadToEnd
    Dim StartIndex As Integer = ContentStr.IndexOf("A SUNOT")
    Dim StrLength As Integer = ContentStr.IndexOf(vbLf, StartIndex) - StartIndex

    RawData.Text = ContentStr.Substring(StartIndex, StrLength)
End Sub
```

Comment: My only issue now is for Track C - RESNO, there is another instance of "C " on the page, since RESNO may change, is there a way to just select this line, no matter what comes after "C"?

Comment: Since there always will be a vbLf before "C ", you can use the following StartIndex instead Dim StartIndex As Integer = ContentStr.IndexOf(vbLf & "C ") + 1